# Unable to de-register from Observable

Tags: java, observer-pattern

I am new to java and learning Observer pattern concept. I am able to successfully create and use Observer and Observable but am unsure how to de-register the Observers. Please find code below.

I have a RandomGenerator class that generates random number between 0-10. This class extends Observable I have a Subsriber class that extends Observer and it wants to "listen" to RandomGenerator and specifically look for numbers greater than 5. In my main method I am instantiating RandomGenerator object and 2 Subscriber objects that register themselves to RandomGenerator.
The Subsriber objects are notified of numbers > 5 but I am not getting how to de-register one of the Subscriber objects and re-test the observer pattern

```
public class RandomGenerator extends Observable{
public int num;
public void generateNums() {

    for(int ii=0; ii<10; ii++) {
        num = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
        if(num >= 5) {
            setChanged();
            notifyObservers();
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("less than 5"+num);
        }
    }
}
}
// Subscriber
public class Subscriber implements Observer{

RandomGenerator observable;

public Subscriber(RandomGenerator observable)
{
    this.observable = observable;
    observable.addObserver(this);
}
@Override
public void update(Observable obj, Object arg) {
    if(obj instanceof RandomGenerator) {
        RandomGenerator gen = (RandomGenerator)obj;
        System.out.println(gen.num);
    }   
}
```

}

```
 //Main method
public class Invoker {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    RandomGenerator gen = new RandomGenerator();
    Subscriber ss1 = new Subscriber(gen);
    Subscriber ss2 = new Subscriber(gen);
    gen.generateNums();
            // how to de-register ss1 and call gen.generateNums();  
}
}
```

Comment: When asking questions like this, you need to specify what `Observable` class you're talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following method to Subscriber.

```
public void disconnect() {
    observable.deleteObserver(this);
}
```

For reference: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/Observable.html